# ValueError: could not convert string to float: in tkinter

Tags: python, string, tkinter, floating-point, tkinter-entry

I could not convert the entry widget values into float for the calculation inside function.

```py
from tkinter import *

def bac_calc():

    #gender_condition
    gend=gender.get()
    if gend == "Male":
        k1=0.015
        k2=0.080
    elif gend == "Female":
        k1=0.020
        k2=0.075
    #weight
    kg=body_weight.get()
    kg=float(kg)
    wt_lbs=kg*2.20462

    bac=k1*k2*wt_lbs*100

    t= "weight in pound is " , float(bac) 
    Label(master, text=t).grid(row=23, column=1)


master = Tk()
master.title('Blood Alcohol Level calculator')


#Gender
gender=StringVar()
Label(master, text="Select your gender").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=5)
r1=Radiobutton(master, text="Male", padx=20, variable=gender, value="Male", command=bac_calc).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W, pady=5)#anchor
r2=Radiobutton(master, text="Female", padx=20, variable=gender, value="Female", command=bac_calc).grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W, pady=5)

#Body weight
Label(master, text="Enter the body weight kg").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, pady=5)
body_weight=Entry(master)
body_weight.grid(row=6, column=2)

#Evaluate and Quit
Button(master, text="Evaluate", command=bac_calc).grid(row=8, column=2, sticky=W, pady=5)
Button(master, text="Quit ", command=master.quit).grid(row=9, column=4, sticky=W, pady=5)

master.mainloop()
```

Can you help me with the problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Sorry for a long code. Anyways,the there are only input widgets and calculations.

Comment: Consider what happens when `bac_calc` gets called if the `body_weight` Entry contains an empty or blank string.

Comment: try `float('')` or `float("Hello")` and you get error too. You can use `try/except` to catch error and do something with it.

Comment: BTW: you will get error when you don't select gender because it will no assign value to `k1`, `k2` - you should use `else` in your `if/elif`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @PM 2Ring, you should consider adding a default value to the `Entry` element represented by `body_weight`.  You can use the `insert` method to do this after creating `body_weight`.

See [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.insert-method).

Answer (score 0):

Ive cleaned up your code a little bit and I've added an error handling statement for your float conversion problem. One thing you might consider doing is finding the formula for BAC calculations that utilizes kilograms instead of converting it to pounds. Also I would recommend looking up the `PEP8 style guides`. It helps keep code readable. Hope this helps :)

```
from tkinter import *


def bac_calc():

    # gender_condition
    gend = gender.get()
    if gend == "Male":
        k1 = 0.015
        k2 = 0.080
    else:
        k1 = 0.020
        k2 = 0.075

    # weight
    try:
        kg = body_weight.get()
        kg = float(kg)
        wt_lbs = kg * 2.20462

        bac = k1 * k2 * wt_lbs * 100

        t = "weight in pound is ", float(bac)
        Label(master, text=t).grid(row=23, column=1)

    except ValueError as e:
        Label(master, text='Input must be numerical.').grid(row=23, column=1)


master = Tk()
master.title('Blood Alcohol Level calculator')

# Gender
gender = StringVar()
Label(master, text="Select your gender").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=5)
r1 = Radiobutton(master, text="Male", padx=20, variable=gender, value="Male", command=bac_calc).grid(row=3, column=2,
                                                                                                     sticky=W,
                                                                                                     pady=5)  # anchor
r2 = Radiobutton(master, text="Female", padx=20, variable=gender, value="Female", command=bac_calc).grid(row=3,
                                                                                                         column=3,
                                                                                                         sticky=W,
                                                                                                         pady=5)

# Body weight
Label(master, text="Enter the body weight kg").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, pady=5)
body_weight = Entry(master)
body_weight.grid(row=6, column=2)

# Evaluate and Quit
Button(master, text="Evaluate", command=bac_calc).grid(row=8, column=2, sticky=W, pady=5)
Button(master, text="Quit ", command=master.quit).grid(row=9, column=4, sticky=W, pady=5)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was using function call on the radio button. That was the mistake for me. Thank you for cleaning the code. Appreciate it alot!!